# how to use BW mapper to replace the values in one XML by another xml?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, tibco

I have following xml:

usa11.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<country  xmlns="http://www.tibco.com/xmlns/ApplicationManagement" >
  <state name="CA">
    <city>
      <street>El Comino Ave.</street>
    <library>library 11111.</library>
    </city>
    <city>
    <street>DeAnza Ave.</street>
  <library>library 22222.</library>
    </city>
    <city>
         <street>shoreline Ave.</street>
    <library>library 33333.</library>
    </city>
  </state>
</country>
```

and another xml:
usa22.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <country xmlns="http://www.tibco.com/xmlns/ApplicationManagement" >
   <state name="CA">
  <city>
           <street>El Comino Ave.</street>
      <library>library AAAAA.</library>
       </city>
  <city>
            <street>DeAnza Ave.</street>
       <library>library BBBBB.</library>
       </city>
  </state>
</country>
```

then I hope to use Tibco BW mapper to use usa22.xml's elements vaules to replace usa11.xml's ones ONLY if their street names are same: then get output usa33.xml as follows  out.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<country xmlns="http://www.tibco.com/xmlns/ApplicationManagement">
  <state name="CA">
      <city>
           <street>El Comino Ave.</street>
           <library>library AAAAA.</library>
      </city>
      <city>
           <street>DeAnza Ave.</street>
           <library>library BBBBB.</library>
      </city>
      <city>
             <street>shoreline Ave.</street>
        <library>library 33333.</library>
      </city>
  </state>
</country>
```

Please throw some lights how to use Tibco BW mapper to do this value replacing??

Schema as follows:

usa.xsd:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.tibco.com/xmlns/ApplicationManagement" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="country">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="state">
        <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="city" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="street"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="library"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name"/>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Thanks so much!!!

Comment: The TIBCO BW Mapper is just a graphical XSLT. If you select the root node of the mapper and copy it and paste it into a text document, you can exit the xslt as normal, then copy it and past it back.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do what you are asking for is to place a XML/Parse XML activity inside a Group in your BW processs, and make it iterate through your usa11.xml. In each loop, you can make the decision by xPath and choose if to replace the contents of the current  
 element or not.

[Link to Designer screenshot](http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/2007/xpath.png)

Hope that helps a bit!